# Dismissing ViewController using Delegation not working iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, delegates

I have two via controllers, a master VC and then a segued VC. Before I segue, I make sure to make the master the delegate to the segued VC. The connection is established.

In the segued VC, there is a button (sort of like a cancel button) that triggers a dismissal. In the segued VC, I have the following code:

```
-(IBAction)deletePill:(id)sender    {
[delegate pillInfoViewControllerDidDeletePill:pill];
```

}

In the master VC, all I have is this:

```
    -(void) pillInfoViewControllerDidDeletePill: (Pill*) pill{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:TRUE completion:nil];
```

}

What am I missing here??

**Update to answer comments and add more code**

To answer the questions and provide more code (I didn't want to do a code dump). I am not presenting this like a model view. A user pushes a button in the master VC that initiates a push segue. Here is the code for the push segue:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UICollectionViewCell *)sender{
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pillInfo"]){
    pills=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[[self fetchedResultsController]fetchedObjects]];
    Pill* pillSelected =pills[sender.tag];
    PillInfoViewController *dest= [segue destinationViewController];
    [dest setPill:pillSelected];
    [dest setDelegate:self];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by dismiss you controller? are you presenting this like modelView?

Comment: where did you assign your delegate?

Comment: I have updated the questions to answer more comments and add more code :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call action of a presenting view controller while dismissing the presented view controller. For this you can use NSNotificationCenter as follows:

```
-(IBAction)deletePill:(id)sender    {
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NotificationName" object:nil];
}
```

Now in master viewcontroller add following code in ViewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(pillInfoViewControllerDidDeletePill)
 name:@"NotificationName" object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

The method

```
-(void) pillInfoViewControllerDidDeletePill: (Pill*) pill
```

should be part of a protocol for example like so:

```
@protocol VCDismissingProtocol
@optional
-(void) pillInfoViewControllerDidDeletePill: (Pill*) pill;
@end
```

Make sure that you've declared that your master view controller implements that protocol:

```
@interface MasterViewController : UIViewController<VCDismissingProtocol>{
...
}
@end
```

and the segued view controller declares a delegate property like so:

```
@property (weak,nonatomic) id <VCDismissingProtocol> delegate;
```

Comment: everything is there. Ugh.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the `[delegate pillInfoViewControllerDidDeletePill:pill];`call and in the implementation of that method look at the delegate object and debug - Is it set correctly? Also you could try to use `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]` instead of `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:TRUE completion:nil]`